# Property behaviour (getter and setter) for a column, instead of normal attribute behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, sqlalchemy

Does SQLAlchemy support something like this:

```
class Character(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'character'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   level = Column(Integer)

   @ColumnProperty(Integer)
   def xp(self):
       return self._xp

   @xp.setter
   def xp(self, value):
       self._xp = value
       while self._xp >= self.xp_to_level_up():
           self.level += 1
           self._xp -= 100

   def __init__(self, level=0, xp=0):
       self.level = level
       self._xp = xp
```

Where `id`, `level`, and `xp` would get stored into the database. So basically a `Column` but instead of an attribute a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `_xp` column definition, that maps to the `xp` column in the table, and use a regular `@property` object to implement your setter logic:

```
class Character(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'character'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    level = Column(Integer)
    _xp = Column('xp', Integer)

    def __init__(self, level=0, xp=0):
        self.level = level
        self._xp = xp

    @property
    def xp(self):
        return self._xp

    @xp.setter
    def xp(self, value):
        self._xp = value
        while self._xp >= self.xp_to_level_up():
            self.level += 1
            self._xp -= 100
```

See [*Naming Columns Distinctly from Attribute Names*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html#naming-columns-distinctly-from-attribute-names).

The above stores the `_xp` attribute on the instance as `xp` in the `character` table, but your code uses the `Character.xp` property to read and write the value of `_xp` indirectly.

You can also use a [`@hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html); this acts just like `property` as used above, but then also lets you use `Character.xp` in query filters:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Character(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'character'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    level = Column(Integer)
    _xp = Column('xp', Integer)

    def __init__(self, level=0, xp=0):
        self.level = level
        self._xp = xp

   @hybrid_property
   def xp(self):
        return self._xp

   @xp.setter
   def xp(self, value):
        self._xp = value
        while self._xp >= self.xp_to_level_up():
            self.level += 1
            self._xp -= 100
```

Now you can use `session.query(Character).filter(Character.xp > 42)` and other such filtering queries, rather than have to use `Character._xp`.

If you want to do bulk updates on your characters, you may have to [include a `update_expression` implementation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#allowing-bulk-orm-update) that would tell SQLAlchemy how to generate a `SET` expression for the `UPDATE`; perhaps using a `CASE` expression to handle updating the level in addition to adjusting XP.

Comment: Thanks! Still hoping to see a property-like column some day ^^

Comment: Such a property would not add anything over the existing option however.

Comment: Surely not in this particular case, but sometimes it'd allow one to have *only* the property column, and nothing else.

Comment: Note that the `Column` object needs to know what attribute it is stored as on the class, since these are descriptor objects really and not (just) entries in the instance `__dict__`. With a `Column` property you'd need to then also register **two** names, the 'hidden' name (here the `_xp` attribute that is the real column) and the 'public' name, (here `xp`). This would make such a property needlessly complicated, when all you need to do is add that `_xp` private attribute explicitly.

Comment: This is not working `session.query(Character).filter(Character.xp==122) `. As you may know how to get the filter() working, please help. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @NamGVU: you'd use `Character._xp == 122` for the solution here. SQLAlchemy also offers the [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), which then acts the way you want it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton! Also found that as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915355/248616

Comment: @NamGVU: I've updated the answer, with a caveat about bulk updates.

Comment: You are the ones who make developers like me to love sqlalchemy and love stackoverflow.com ^^ Great thanks!